# Spring JsonView unnest nested fields

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

I have something similar to these two classes:

```
public class User {
    @JsonView(UserView.IdOnly.class)
    int userID;

    String name;
}

public class Project {
    @JsonView(ProjectView.IdOnly.class)
    int projectID;

    @JsonView(ProjectView.Summary.class)
    // JPA annotations ommitted
    User user;
}
```

And the following View classes:

```
public class UserView extends View {}

public class ProjectView extends View {
    public interface Summary extends IdOnly {}
}

public class View {
    public interface IdOnly {}
}
```

My controller is as follows:

```
@JsonView(ProjectView.Summary.class)
@RequestMapping(value="/project/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List getProjects() {
    return repository.findAll();
}
```

The JSON output, as you can see, wraps the userID inside the User object:

```
[
  {
    "projectID": 1,
    "user": {
      "userID": 1
    }
  }
]
```

This works as expected, and I can have my clients work with it, but it doesn't seem finished... I would like to get rid of the "user" wrapper:

```
[
  {
    "projectID": 1,
    "userID": 1
  }
]
```

Is there a way to do this cleanly? Preferably by using another annotation. I don't have any custom serializers yet and I would hate to have to start using them. If this can't be done with JsonViews, is there an alternative?

I know one solution would be to add a userID field to the Project class, but the setter would need a call to the repository (to also update the user field) which would mess up my class diagram.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there's an annotation called `@JsonUnwrapped` that removes the object wrapper, and all properties within it are included in the parent object.

http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: That does look promising! I see it has a property "enabled", could I set this to true if the controller method is marked with an @JsonView and to false if it isn't?

Comment: The property `enabled` is set to true by default according to the docs. I think having both `@JsonUnwrapped` and `@JsonView` annotations on a property is an issue -  [https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1046](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1046). I'd have to dig further. It's really interesting!